Multiple ggplot legends: How do you adjust one of them?
I would like to access only of the legend below, carb and setting the font size to 20. How can I do that. The code below changes both legends.
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = carb, shape = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20))


You can set individual theme elements for a legend inside the function guides(). In your case, the legend for carb is a colorbar mapped to the color aesthetic, so we can do
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = carb, shape = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(
           theme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20))
    )
  )



Thanks! What would it look like if I wanted to change something for the Fill title or if I would map something to shape/size?

It's always guides(aesthetic = guide_x(...)), so e.g. guides(fill = guide_colorbar(...)) or guides(shape = guide_legend(...)) etc.

From @Axeman comment:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = carb, shape = as.factor(am), size = vs, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(theme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 4, color = "red"))),
         shape = guide_legend(theme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 8, color = "green"))),
         size   = guide_legend(theme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "yellow"))),
         fill = guide_legend(theme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "orange"))))
                       

and here is the official documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html
